# I want to retrieve the names of running apps in my iphone app

Tags: iphone

I want to retrieve the name of all apps which are running in the background , it is possible in iOS?

Comment: You can get a list of processes, as seen in the iStat app. I posted some code for that here: http://forrst.com/posts/UIDevice_Category_For_Processes-h1H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, no. Technically, no apps are "running" in a true sense, in the background on iOS. Fast app switching in iOS 4 means some apps are still in memory when they are suspended but they might be unloaded at any point if the OS requires.

Apps can make use of a small number of background services such as background audio, voip and location services. Each of these has their own API so there is no way to query if any Apps in the background are using them generically.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely No (without jailbreaking).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by known api just with undocumented api.

Answer (score 0):

You are not permitted to interact with other applications installed in the iOS, not even detecting if they are running, installed, or what they are named.